# business vetted SSL vs domain vetted SSL

Tags: https

Does Google Rank business vetted SSL higher than domain vetted SSL’s?

I did a lot of searching but was not able to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

An organization ssl site can be a known spammer. A domain ssl can be stackoverflow.com. Which one would Google rank higher?

My point is always this: content overrides everything. While you may get a couple of extra brownie points for having an "organizational ssl" and running a legitimate business, legitimate and relevant content is always far, FAR more important.

Almost anything else is just smoothing the icing or cooking the books.

Answer (score 1):

Spammers usually try to spend as little as possible for their domain because they know it will be throw away.   Showing Google that you have spent more money makes Google less likely to think your new domain name will be spam.

Yes, the content will matter, but initially you are more likely to be trusted by search engines more quickly when you spend money in ways they can see:

- Buying a domain name
- Registering that domain name for multiple years
- Getting an SSL certificate
- Getting a higher level SSL certificate

I wouldn't do any of those things *just* for SEO.   But they may get your site some rankings in three months when it would normally take six.